# Response.redirect working In FF but problem with IE

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to redirect from one page to another based on condition .

For e.g I want to redirect from www.abcd.com/Doc/blogs.aspx to www.abcd.com/movies based on condition which I need to check from code behind C#

I was trying to use `Response.Redirect("movies.aspx");`

but its not working in IE7

I am getting Http 400 bad request....
whereas in Firefox its working fine any idea how to resolve this  problem

If anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Response.Redirect("~/movies.aspx");`